# tsconfig.js exclude property not working when import modules is used

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I am going nuts currently why my typescript compilation (tsc) is always trying to compile node_modules files even when I've specified to exclude this folder.

[**tl;dr;** : *it's because I have imports but I don't know how to exclude imports from compilation*]

I'm using Visual Studio Code, but have the same issue when running tsc directly from commandline

My project structure is a typical one :

```
.
|
--node_modules\..
|
--src\..
|
--typings
```

In my root I have a **tsconfig.json** with following content:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "watch": false
 },
 "compileOnSave": true,
 "exclude":
 [
  "node_modules"
 ]
}
```

But when I compile (using tsc directly in commandline or through visual studio code) I see a zillion of errors from \node_modules\angular..

Now, I *do* use import statements in my typescript files (because I want to use webpack in the end):

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import router from 'angular-ui-router';
```

So, it seems the typescript compiler tries to import these angular modules AND compile...

I tried to use the **--noResolve** option in the tsconfig.json, but then my source files throw errors that they cannot find these modules..

**I there any way I can tell the typescript compiler to *not compile* imported modules from folder xyz ?**

Comment: You can check the version of TS you are using, perhaps it does not support `exclude`?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Yes, forgot to mention, I did that. I originally had 1.5.8, then upgraded to latest and now have 2.0.9

Comment: To be honest, I never got this "exclude" working and used "include" instead :) That is usually a better alternative if you can manage that (not always unfortunately)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik yes, tried that too. _"include": ["src"]_ but that also pulls the angular modules in (through the import I guess).. even tried to move my tsconfig.json to the src folder, goes bad too

Comment: well I suppose it needs the `.d.ts` anyway, so you won't get rid of that. But it should not compile the `.js` files, are you sure that js gets compiled?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik your reference to use "include" instead prompted me to look further.. finally made it working with the new --slipLibCheck flag and _not_ specifying either include nor exclude (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#user-content-new---skiplibcheck)

Comment: Wow, that's looks very useful. It was so slow doing all that stuff and you can't use strictNullChecks with Angular2 e.g. But what you say means that actually nothing was compiled as I thought. It's only `.d.ts` files

Answer (score 1):

In the end, my solution was not by adjusting my tsconfig.json file,
but to call the compiler with the new **--skipLibCheck** flag (added in TypeScript 2.0 - see [here in the typescript wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#user-content-new---skiplibcheck))

> >tsc --skipLibCheck

I also removed the *exclude* property from my tsconfig.json (as the "**exclude**" property defaults to excluding the node_modules anyway when not specified (see in the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)).

Comment: Thanks, finally something that helped me!

Comment: When I do `import passport from 'passport` I am still getting an error for `passport.authenticate.mockReturnValue(user);` in my excluded file where my tsconfig has `"skipLibCheck": true,`. This answer is mentioned here and a couple other SO questions but hasn't helped me. Any idea there @aardvark71?