# skip library check only in node_modules

Tags: typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

There are several questions about disabling errors in mistyped `node_modules` (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906424/rxjs5-typescript-typings-fail/49912245#49912245), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547903/tsconfig-js-exclude-property-not-working-when-import-modules-is-used/40563012#40563012)), but they all involve using the `skipLibCheck` compiler flag.

Are there other solutions to this problem (e.g., using `include` or  `exclude`)? I have a couple of hand-written `.d.ts` files (stricter types than available on DefinitelyTyped) that I'd like to type check, so the wholesale disabling of typechecking on these files is not appealing.

Comment: Wow, you even take the trouble to enhance existing lib with stricter types! Perhaps consider also amend those with wrong types?

Comment: Titian show the source code so he's probably right. Maybe consider alternative solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322788/)

Comment: There's an opened [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30511) with a feature request for this.

Answer (score 13):

There is no granular control over type checking, you either check all declaration files or none unfortunately. From compiler code:

```
export function skipTypeChecking(sourceFile: SourceFile, options: CompilerOptions) {
    // If skipLibCheck is enabled, skip reporting errors if file is a declaration file.
    // If skipDefaultLibCheck is enabled, skip reporting errors if file contains a
    // '/// <reference no-default-lib="true"/>' directive.
    return options.skipLibCheck && sourceFile.isDeclarationFile || options.skipDefaultLibCheck && sourceFile.hasNoDefaultLib;
}
```

Comment: Is there any plans/proposals in TS compiler to change that? So it allows skipping one or more declaration files or libs?