# how to make skipLibCheck ignore only d.ts in dependencies but not our own d.ts file?

Tags: typescript, types, tsc, compiler-options, .d.ts

as title

some library are just poorly typed and throw error everywhere which is why I want to skip the library type

however, I don't want to skip checking on my own d.ts file because the compiler won't throw errors upon implicit any type and type not found which is an issue

how can I solve this?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [skip library check only in node\_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985943/skip-library-check-only-in-node-modules)